# Cannot start gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the code using

- source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
- sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
- sudo easy_install rosinstall
- mkdir -p ~/ros-gazebo/workspace
- rosinstall ~/ros-gazebo /opt/ros/diamondback ~/ros-gazebo/workspace
- cd ~/ros-gazebo/workspace
- svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/diamondback
  simulator_gazebo
- source ~/ros-gazebo/setup.bash
- rosmake gazebo

The same procedure is also described in [this post.](http://answers.ros.org/question/1701/implementation-of-header-files)

Now when i use 'roslaunch gazebo_worlds wg_world.launch' it gives me the following error.

/home/student/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/build/server/gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libparallel_quickstep.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any idea how to fix this problem??

PS: i have one instalation in /opt/ros. and this installation is in /home/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10833/cannot-start-gazebo??/) by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-07**:
No i am writing the correct command, now i am making with rosmake gazebo_worlds and see what is the outcome..

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-07**:
by the way, might be a typo, 'roslaunch gazebo_world wg_world.launch' should be 'roslaunch gazebo_worlds wg_world.launch'?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-08-05**:
Is parallel_quickstep installed and on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-08-05**:
For me, these steps were working. I just tried. Did you do anything else? Is your gazebo checkout maby dirty? (roscd gazebo; svn st, then check if something is marked with M for modified). If so, make a backup, delete the directory ~/ros-gazebo and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did `rosmake gazebo` return any errors?  If the build was successful, when you roslaunch any gazebo world launch files, it should have invoked the following binary:

```
/home/student/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gazebo
```

not

```
/home/student/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/build/server/gazebo
```

This seems to suggest the build did not complete.  Can you verify and check the console output of the rosmake command?

The version of the gazebo binary referenced in your original question will not have the correct link paths setup, hence you see the error with not finding the `libparallel_quickstep.so` library.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-08**:
removing the file called 'installed' simply forces make to do a recompile + install in case the previous installs left system in a bad state.

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-07**:
after applying the steps it gives no error and the system now works... thanks for the help..  but i want to know that rm installed removes the previous installation or what it is doing.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-07**:
Please make from within ' ~/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/' to make sure the correct gazebo binary is installed.  Performing make in ' ~/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/build' is not sufficient.  What happens when you do, 'roscd gazebo; rm installed; make;'?

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-07**:
/home/student/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/sensors/ir is the full path to the IRSensor.cc,  or from the website https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/browser/server#sensors/ir is the same. btw i didn't patch anything yet. i want to patch the IRSensor.cc

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-08-07**:
What happens when you do, 'roscd gazebo; rm installed; make;'?  Also, what is full path of the file (IRSensor.cc) that you patched?  Lastly, can you post the patch?  Thanks.

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-07**:
After rosmake gazebo_worlds,, the error disappeared but when i try to 'make' ~/ros-gazebo/workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/build,,, here ,, the error comes again. As i want to change the file IRSensor.cc, because the GetIRCount function in this file is not working. so i did make here.

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-07**:
When i try to roslaunch with my original path /opt/ros/diamondback.... it works but when i try with path ~/ros-gazebo/workspace/diamondback..:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH then the roslaunch gives me an error